# Как поместить текст в буфер обмена?

Tags: c#

Я пишу программу, которая генерирует строку, которую мне надо сохранить в буфер обмена:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string psw = "";

    // ... тут остальной код ...

    Console.Write($"\nВаш пароль: {psw}");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.WriteLine("Cкопировать сгенирированный пароль в буфер обмена?  #");

    int p = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (p == 1)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(psw); // ???
        Console.Write("\n Ваш пароль успешно скопирован в системный буфер обмена.");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Там, где знаки вопроса, можно как-то сделать, чтобы копировало код в буфер обмена?

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть по этой ссылке. Возможно, это то, что вы ищете

[ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: @АнтонК. я только от туда , но вот проблему не могу решить, ошибка

Comment: Нужно подключить к проекту библиотеку, в которой есть класс для работы с буфером обмена. На выбор [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) - первая из WPF, вторая - из WinForms. Когда читаете документацию, читайте её внимательно. Обратите внимание на надписи Assembly. Подключите либо PresentationCore.dll, либо System.Windows.Forms.dll. И откройте пространство имён: Namespace.

Comment: Ещё на англоязычной версии есть такой ответ 
[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205260/net-core-copy-to-clipboard)

Comment: Проще создать UI-приложение, например Winforms и сделать это всё там.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте библиотеку System.Windows.Forms.
Main метод обязательно должен иметь атрибут [STAThread].
Само использование Clipboard.SetText(string); у вас правильное.